# if keys[K_UP] is not working, how can i fix it?

Tags: python, pygame

I'm making a pong game to learn more about pygame and than i came on this problem:

```
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[K_UP]:
    y -= 1
if keys[K_DOWN]:
    y += 1
```

It returns "name K_UP is not defined".

All the solutions i found resulted in spaghetti code or extreme lag.
Does anyone knows how to solve this?

Comment: In your own words, why do you expect `K_UP` to be defined? What happened when you tried reading the documentation? Specifically, what did it say about where the constants come from?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either

```py
from pygame.locals import *
```

or

```py
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_UP]:
    y -= 1
if keys[pygame.K_DOWN]:
    y += 1
```

See [`pygame.key`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/key.html) module.